# Textbox Validation in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, textbox

I was wondering if there is a way to validate input in textboxes in xaml? I've seen a lot of examples doing it in the code behind, which is fine if that's what it comes down too. I just have a few textboxes where I want to validate that the input is a positive number, and another that the input is a number between -180 and +180.

Comment: You can use ValidationRule or IDataErrorInfo for validation

Comment: Read a bit about ValidationRule. I'll look into IDataErrorInfo now. Looks like there isn't a way to do it strictly in XAML from what I can find. Thanks for the response!

Comment: XAML is for layout.  Equal comparison in trigger is about the most logic you are going to do in XAML.

Answer (score 2):

If your Model or ViewModel implements [`IDataErrorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and your binding includes [`ValidatesOnDataErrors=true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesondataerrors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you'll see the standard `TextBox` surrounded by a red border when the value fails validation.

Be aware you'll also want `UpdatesourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in order to make validation happen as a user is typing - otherwise they'll only see validation set or clear when the `TextBox` loses focus